# Trying to restrict editing of an object to the object's owner or is_staff in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm almost there but I can't quite get this.

I've got a custom permission setup:

```
from rest_framework.permissions import BasePermission, SAFE_METHODS

class IsOwnerOrStaff(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return view.action == 'retrieve' or request.user.is_staff

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in SAFE_METHODS:
            return True

        return request.user.is_staff or obj == request.user
```

And a User View that does this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework import permissions

from .serializers import UserSerializer
from .permissions import IsOwnerOrStaff

class ViewMixins(object):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, IsOwnerOrStaff,)

class UserViewSet(ViewMixins, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    model = User
```

Everything works for when `request.user.is_staff` and there are permission controls on the not staff user. But, the NOT staff user can't do anything on their own record except view it.

I THOUGHT that the `if request.method in SAFE_METHODS` would allow that to pass through but I seem to be missing something.

Suggestions welcome.

BTW: I want a user.is_staff to be able to do anything and a user that is NOT staff to only be able to GET/PUT/PATCH/POST on their OWN record.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is even easier than what you are trying. Override the get_queryset method of your view:

```
    if self.request.user.is_superuser:
       return Model.objects.all()
    else:
       return Model.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
```

ofc, you need a field in your model pointing to the creator/owner.

More info [Django-rest-framework permissions for create in viewset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22760191/django-rest-framework-permissions-for-create-in-viewset/22767325#22767325)

Comment: Well, now I'm confused. That is so easy. Why would I need to write custom permissions then?

Comment: For advanced filtering. For example, if you have to control wether a user has the add_vegetables permission when creating a receipt which involves vegetables (just to say something).